# JQuery IE bind this

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

In IE I am getting this error in the console using JQuery:

*SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' 
default.js, line 33 character 3*

```
$.get(URL + 'dashboard/photoList/'+categoryID, (function(o) {
        // code here
}).bind(this));
```

Is there a work around to binding 'this'? I'm used to this from prototype.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bind` is only available in browsers supporting ECMAScript 5. Unlike (apparently) Prototype.js, jQuery does not extend built-in objects.

jQuery offers [`$.proxy` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$.get(URL + 'dashboard/photoList/'+categoryID, $.proxy(function(o) {
        // code here
},this));
```

Comment: Wow it would have taken me FOREVER to find this out, thanks! LOL