# onClick Not Working In Internet Explorer, Looking for Workaround

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, onclick, onchange

I'm working on a video gallery page where there are 6 thumbnails and the user can click on them to play the corresponding video.

Of course, there are more than 6 videos total, so users can navigate through various categories/pages.

Take a look:
[Video Gallery Rough](http://www.nba.com/warriors/testinghtmlxml_375.html)

Everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but clicking on the thumbnails does not work in Internet Explorer. I've done some research and it seems as though onClick has issues in IE, but none of the solutions I've found have worked.

Basically the video thumbnails are in a table, and each  has an onClick event:

```
<td id='videoBox1td' onClick=''>
```

When the user loads/switches pages, jQuery() dynamically edits the onClick attribute:

```
$('#videoBox' + i + 'td').attr({'onClick':'frames[\'videourl\', videoPlaylist);'});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your js in the onClick seems a bit malformed: `frames[\'videourl\', videoPlaylist);`

Comment: thats the js i have to use to get it to play in the frame. works in chrome+ff, the issue is with onClick not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
    $('#videoBox' + i + 'td').bind("click", function () {
        ... do stuff here...
    }
```

Comment: This is almost working, however it seems to be binding the link for the 6th video to all of them: [link](http://www.nba.com/warriors/testinghtmlxml_388.html). i is iterating properly so i can't understand why it overwrites other videoboxes :(

Comment: I have an XML where I pull the link from like: `var linkhtml=x[i].getElementsByTagName("linkhtml")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;`. then where you have 'do stuff here', i have: `frames['nbaTeamArticlePlayer20091214141222'].playVideo(linkhtml, videoPlaylist20091214141222);` which applies the links correctly. however once i click on any of the thumbnails, it calls on what the variable linkhtml equals now, which is the last video after the iterations

Comment: My guess that the problem is in your click function.  You probably have a variable in there for the link and you change its value in your loop, expecting it to hold that value when the call back actually happens?  I'm pretty sure that's not the way it will work.  The variable will just get overwritten which is why you see the value for the last iteration(my guess the 6th?).  To get around this problem you might want to use bind to override what the "this" keyword means, and use this to refer to the link that's relevant to the current iteration somehow.

Comment: $('#videoBox' + i + 'td').bind("click", function () {
    frames['nbaTeamArticlePlayer20091214141222'].playVideo(this, videoPlaylist20091214141222);
    }.bind(linkhtml));

Comment: i see what you mean and i understand but I'm not sure how to fix it. putting.bind(linkhtml) after the close curly brace like that doesn't seem to be working (just doesn't play any video now). should i just create six different linkhtml variables? seems odd that that would be the best way... thank you for all your help so far btw

Comment: Well if you are always going to have a set number of links, then just hard code them. If not, try making linkhtml a javascript object first, then I'm pretty sure it will work since I have tried doing something like this previously.  However, keep in mind that even if this works, hard coding it is still ideal if you can get away with it because Safari does not understand .bind on functions so this code will not work in Safari.

Comment: oh i didn't know this didn't work in safari... i need a cross browser solution. there are too many links to hard code. what if instead of .bind() i used .mousedown()?

Comment: "$('#videoBox' + i + 'td').bind("click", function (){...stuff...}" will work fine in Safari since that's a jQuery method.  "function (){...stuff...}.bind()" will not since its a browser specific thing.  These binds do different things, I think you have them confused.  Anyway, I actually don't know how to solve the link variable problem you are having without changing what the "this" keyword means.  But it seems like this would be a common problem to have, so I guess you might find the answer by doing some more googling.  Sorry.

Comment: @DougieBear Hey, I found the cross browser workaround to .bind on functions to define a custom context.  You can use juqery.proxy instead to return a new function that has the context you define.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575518/jquery-ie-bind-this